# Difference colour right/left page on photo

Tags: export

I've been creating photobooks on inDesign for a while now. Never had this problem:

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is the extra image i created to see if the problem repeats itself:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: photo is of course the same but appears different whether left or right page.]

It only seems to be the case when a photo overlaps the middle of the book. 
Also, i created a new page compeletely virgin to try again inside the document and it would appear there is no problem.

Is it possible there is some sort of invisible "layer" appearing for some reason.

Any idea ? 
Thanks a million

Comment: Sorry, i wrote the explanation in the html of the photo. Doesnt appear.. 

So: in the program, the photo shows a color unity (like a normal photo) and when i export, the result is as such. Different color for different page (right or left). 

I'm really confused, never happened to me before and all my friends who know indesign have never seen this

Comment: I am no InDesign expert, however I suspect if you want a solution you are going to have to supply more information for users here to answer properly. Perhaps consider adding a screenshots of the arrangement of your layers, and perhaps your PDF export settings. To me it looks like there is something like a semi-transparent rectangle in your layers that is covering the photograph, but I can't tell for sure without access to your file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have printed with Blurb a few times and remember they are using a particular export preset for their PDFs. Try exporting without that preset and instead use one of the default presets in InDesign like the 'High Quality Print' or the 'Smallest File Size' and see if that works. In which case the issue would be the Blurb preset.

Comment: THANK YOU everyone, 

I just found out what the problem was. 
All the pages that were suffering from that 'layer' were actually pages  i had added some text on. 
As i put the text opacity to 80%, it also impacted the rest of the page. 

That's it!
Thanks again, really appreciate the quick response

Comment: @JEANBIFEAN If you found the solution, please consider adding it as an answer and marking it correct. That way, you'll help out a future visitor who has the same problem. And it's good for site stats, and gives you some reputation to boot :) Thanks!

Comment: Sorry and thanks. 
I think i did. Not sure where to do it. 
If i didn't make it, feel free to do it.